# (BadRequestKeyError) Don't know where the problem is

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, flask, key

Im trying to make a sign up page and on the page there are two password fields, one for the password itself and the second to confirm the password (and of course a username):

## HTML:

```
<div class="fields">
    <input id="usr" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input id="confirmpass" type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm password" required>
</div>
```

I know what the error is and means, it's a `KeyError` meaning that it can't find the key i've passed into `requests.form`, most cases of these errors are misspellings so I checked the spelling multiple times and even copy and pasted the same string.

My problem is that I don't know why the third field^ isn't in `requests.form`, maybe it's because I have two password types? But I haven't seen anything anywhere saying that it's not allowed.

## Error:

```
File ...
if request.form["confirm_password"]==request.form["password"]
File ...
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

The error gets raised before the webpage even loads up by the way, not when I submit the form.

## Python:

```
# Accounts = JSON File
@app.route("/signup",methods=["GET","POST"])
def signup():
    if request.method=="GET":
        if request.form["confirm_password"]==request.form["password"]: # Where the error traces back to
            if request.form["username"]not in Accounts.keys():
                Accounts[request.form["username"]]=Accounts["Default"]
                Accounts[request.form["username"]]["Password"]=request.form["password"]
                redirect(url_for("login",name=request.form["username"]))
            else:return render_template(Signup,valid="Username already taken",name=request.form["username"])
        else:return render_template(Signup,valid="Password confirmation does not match password",name=request.form["username"])
    else:return render_template(Signup)
```

My login page works perfectly it's just this.

Comment: @mechanical_meat It works! Thanks a lot, such a stupid mistake XD, I even had the form request set to `POST` in the DOM as well.

Comment: It's ok. I wasn't actually sure for a second about the possibility of sending form data using HTTP GET so I removed my comment, but I determined that it wasn't what you were trying to do because you don't have anything to get the values from the URL.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working :)

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why you removed the comment, answer the question if you want for the reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've set up your route indicates that you're expecting to receive a POST request. So your code is currently incorrectly expecting a GET request.

The quick fix is to change the first line of the route to:

```
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...
```